# How to end a relationship with a recruitment company?

Tags: recruitment, legal

Three months ago, I, a Swedish citizen, was approached by a recruitment company since they found information about me on LinkedIn which might suit a position for a job in Sweden.

Many things happened during half a week, but after that nothing has happened.

I have sent them my CV and confirmed that they can represent me, but no real papers has been signed, only email-conversation.

I had a phone meeting with a person at the company who was hiring, but he clearly said that they would not hire me through the recruitment company.

The person whom represented me does not respond to emails I send and yesterday I learned that he had left the recruitment company.

I doubt very much that this UK-based recruitment company will be able to find me anymore positions in Sweden. So I don't want to have any more connection with them and want to leave in proper way so that I will not be legally responsible for them in the future when seeking other opportunities in Sweden.

How do I terminate the relationship with this company?

Is it enough to write them an email and tell them to delete my CV and all my details?

Or am I bound to any legal requirements that never was presented to me in any email conversation?

On the phone yesterday someone said that they I was linked to them forever.

I have sent them my CV and confirmed that they can represent me, but no real papers has been signed, only email-conversation.

They contacted me, not the other way around.

I actually saw this opportunity prior to being contacted by the recruiter company, but did not act on it quick enough, I think it was just a few days after it disappeared from the job market in Sweden that I decided to give it a go, but then it has disappeared from the site I first spotted it.
So now I cannot apply for the job since the guy I spoke to in the company is not allowed by his manager to use the recruiter company due to cost issues, the commission you mention.
Someone I spoke to in the recruiter company told me that there was a 6 month limit for either me or the hiring company or both before I could apply without getting into trouble related to the commission, but I don't know from what date the 6 months are counted and the last guy I spoke to never mentioned this.
I think they don't want to let go of me because of the commission, but since I have not signed any contract with them, just been using email, I feel that they cannot prevent me forever to apply for new jobs. 
Turning 60 next month means that this might have been the last opportunity for me to get a new job, but alas I am stuck with the situation I am in, not knowing what to do in this case.

Comment: Have you signed anything with them?

Comment: "Forever" is unenforceable.  But as above, have you signed anything?

Comment: On the phone with who, the recruiter company?

Comment: See below for more details

Comment: Hi Arne, generally when you have updates to your question it is best to edit into your question rather than adding answers. Answers are meant to be used to provide comprehensive answers to your question. I edited this into your question. Welcome!

Comment: I added the second answer to my first, how do I get rid of the second one, Enderland?

Answer (score 6):

Please note that I am not a lawyer. If you are concerned, I would consult with a qualified legal professional.

> How do I terminate the relationship with this company? Is it enough to write them an email and tell them to delete my CV and all my details? Or am I bound to any legal requirements that never was presented to me in any email conversation? On the phone yesterday someone said that they I was linked to them forever.

Unless you have signed an agreement with them, there should be no exclusivity or other means of (1) requiring you to find employment with them or (2) preventing you from finding employment separately or through another recruiter. In other words, you really do not have a relationship.

If you do not want to use their services, do not communicate with them further and refuse any interviews or employment offers they provide. If the are being overly aggressive or pushy, stand firm. If they start harassing you, contact the police.

However, the recruitment agency usually has a legal agreement with the hiring organization. If they contact you as a potential new employee but you then bypass them and go to the hiring organization, the recruitment agency may be able to claim their commission still. Without access to that agreement it is hard to be more specific.

I would still approach the hiring organization directly and start the application process. If you did not give the recruitment agency verbal or written consent to apply for the job on your behalf (you may need to sign a statutory declaration or similar legal document to that effect) and you can point a separate source for the job (such as the advertisement you mention), you might be OK. Be honest with the hiring company about your situation and try to work with them as best you can.

As for removing your details from the recruitment agency, I am not familiar with Swedish law but, generally speaking, you can ask but they need not comply. Even if they did, you have made details about yourself public, such as the LinkedIn profile you mentioned, and they could always use that. As @Philipp and others have mentioned, EU privacy laws apply, which could be useful. However, this also does not affect your job application.

While you are older than many job seekers, I would not lose hope about finding a job, either. Have confidence in yourself, keep your skills up to date and keep applying. If you are good at what you do and keep trying, you will find a suitable role.

Comment: The issue here is that I might be able to find a position with the company I have been in contact with via the recruitment company directly via an advertisement on the Swedish job market, but then I or the company may get into to legal issues if they hire me.
I am 60 years old and I will not get that many chances to find a new job, so that is why I am eager to get out the recruitment company's 'claws'.

Comment: I am not familiar with Swedish privacy laws, but Sweden is in the EU, so the European data protection directive applies to them. The implementation of that directive varies from EU country to EU country, but the implementations of some countries says that companies *do* need to comply when a person asks for deletion of their personal data.

Comment: Arne: depending on you contract with the recruiter and exactly how the two jobs are related ... and law in your country,  which I suggest you get expert advice on -- the worst tjat could happen is that someone owes the recruiter their commission. And that should only be the case if there's some evidence that you discovered the opportunity due in part to the recruiter's work. I suspect you're safe, but you may want to find out what the recruiter thinks the contract days, and then have a lawyer confirm or refute that.

Comment: See comment added above

Comment: Bottom line is it’s not ethical for the hiring company to hire someone direct that got brought to them through a recruiter, so they won’t do it because that relationship and their reputation is more important to them than you are.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you have a legal relationship with the recruitment agency. At one time you agreed to let them act as a middleman for you - they forwarded your CV to some company but they didn't pay you for it. And now if you "cancel" the relationship they are not out anything. You can't be tricked into legal obligations, if they expect you to follow some agreement with them then they should at least have sent you a copy of it.

I would just send them a quick email asking them not to forward your CV to anyone. Include enough details so they can find and delete your CV from their database.

Comment: Hi!

My situation especially in my work life, has changed a lot since this issue was current, so I see no need to do anything now or in the future.
(And the guy that had the contact with me has also left that company, so I guess I will not here from them ever again. If they do, I will let them know that they cannot offer me anything that I might be interested in, ever.)
I still want to thank you for the interest you have in my issue, but it is now obsolete.

Arne.